# Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication error on Android

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to verify the Phone number with Firebase Auth but it gives the following error,

Notes :
My sha1 and sha256 keys are attached.
It works when I manually add the phone number to firebase.
Works smoothly on iOS devices.

[GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config.

```
{
"error":{
  "code":400,
  "message":"INVALID_CERT_HASH",
  "errors":[
     {
        "message":"INVALID_CERT_HASH",
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"invalid"
     }
  ]
}
}
```

output :

```
I/chatty  (10469): uid=10134(com.xxx.xxx) identical 1 line
W/xxx.xxx(10469): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;- 
>putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/System  (10469): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value 
was null.
D/EGL_emulation(10469): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7a08b7442b80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 
0x7a08b7299680)
E/FirebaseAuth(10469): [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project 
config. Failed with {
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):   "error": {
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):     "code": 400,
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):     "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH",
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):     "errors": [
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):       {
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):         "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH",
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):         "domain": "global",
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):         "reason": "invalid"
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):       }
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):     ]
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):   }
E/FirebaseAuth(10469): }
E/FirebaseAuth(10469):  400
E/zzf     (10469): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token - calling backend 
without app verification
D/EGL_emulation(10469): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7a08b7442b80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 
0x7a08b7299680)
W/System  (10469): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value 
was null.
E/FirebaseAuth(10469): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code 
request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
I/flutter (10469): exception
I/flutter (10469): [firebase_auth/missing-client-identifier] This 
request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither 
SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or 
check the logcat for more details.
W/GoogleApiManager(10469): com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api- 
phone.zzv could not execute call because it requires feature 
(sms_retrieve, 1).
W/GoogleApiAvailability(10469): GMS core API Availability. 
ConnectionResult=2, tag=null
W/GoogleApiAvailability(10469): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same error because **I generated my sha1 certificate through vscode terminal** which is bad if you want phone auth.
so i fixed by

1. open my android folder through android studio
2. click `.android/app/build.gradle`
3. choose gradle view on the left side of the android studio
4. choose `android>task>signReport`
5. wait some time and you will get the real sha! certificate
6. there copy and past firebase project.

if those does'nt work then check

1. if you enabled phone authenticatin from firebase auth
2. then enable [android deviceCheck Api](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com)

Comment: My sha1 and sha256 keys are attached.

Comment: did you get it from android studio if it is not you need to get it only ! android studio

Comment: enable android deviceCheck Api helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency to your build.gradle file

implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

check app/build.gradle contain following code for debug and release

```
signingConfigs {
   debug {
       keyAlias keystoreDevProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreDevProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreDevProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreDevProperties['storeFile']) : null
       storePassword keystoreDevProperties['storePassword']
   }
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please don't include your code as an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Instead, please [edit] your answer to include your code as [formatted text](/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

@Ufuk Zimmerman May the creating certificate by `android > task  > signingReport` work for you for debug but when you create signed `.apk` you need to use a keystore (.jks) file and you need to create SHA by the same keystore I think for this the best way to use command to get SHA.

`keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name_with_complete_path} -alias {alias_name}`

example

`keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.jks -alias test`